# Non linear interpolation to find the missing values using R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a data.table `test_dt`, in which some of the values are missing for each `group`. Can someone suggest the fastest way to interpolate and fill the missing value?

In the graph form `x-axis` is column `a` and `y-axis` is column `b`, hench the interval distance of column `a` should be considered while predicting `b`.

```
test_dt = structure(list(group = c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1"), a = c(165, 170, 185, 195, 200, 210, 220, 240, 1, 1.5, 2, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 7, 10), b = c(1.925, 0.575, 0.3, NA, NA, 2.825, 9.05, 27.9, 3.775, 3.225, 2.75, 0.255, 0.04, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), index = integer(0))
> test_dt 
    group     a      b
 1:    B1 165.0  1.925
 2:    B1 170.0  0.575
 3:    B1 185.0  0.300
 4:    B1 195.0     NA
 5:    B1 200.0     NA
 6:    B1 210.0  2.825
 7:    B1 220.0  9.050
 8:    B1 240.0 27.900
 9:    C1   1.0  3.775
10:    C1   1.5  3.225
11:    C1   2.0  2.750
12:    C1   4.5  0.255
13:    C1   5.0  0.040
14:    C1   5.5     NA
15:    C1   7.0     NA
16:    C1  10.0     NA
```

Following are some conditions -

1. Interpolated values should not be zero or negative value
2. Interpolated values should not be a copy of the last non-NA value

I tried to solve it using `na.spline` but the result is not correct, especially for group `C1`, where value of column `a` is 7 and 10

```
test_dt[, predicted := zoo::na.spline(zoo(.SD), x = a)[, 2], by = c("group")]
> test_dt
    group     a      b   predicted
 1:    B1 165.0  1.925  1.92500000
 2:    B1 170.0  0.575  0.57500000
 3:    B1 185.0  0.300  0.30000000
 4:    B1 195.0     NA  0.18981191
 5:    B1 200.0     NA  0.40167712
 6:    B1 210.0  2.825  2.82500000
 7:    B1 220.0  9.050  9.05000000
 8:    B1 240.0 27.900 27.90000000
 9:    C1   1.0  3.775  3.77500000
10:    C1   1.5  3.225  3.22500000
11:    C1   2.0  2.750  2.75000000
12:    C1   4.5  0.255  0.25500000
13:    C1   5.0  0.040  0.04000000
14:    C1   5.5     NA  0.03038963
15:    C1   7.0     NA  1.67389631
16:    C1  10.0     NA 16.44642968
```

**Update - 1**
Following is the second dataset. Using the solutions below, the predicted values are very high.

```
temp_dt = structure(list(group = c("K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", 
"K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", "K1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F1", "F1"), a = c(185, 190, 195, 200, 202.5, 205, 210, 212.5, 
215, 217.5, 220, 222.5, 225, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 35), b = c(NA, 
NA, 0.45, 0.6, 1.05, 1.45, 2.7, 3.125, 4.3, NA, 7.05, 8.95, 10.35, 
0.5, 0.7, 0.925, 1.2, 1.75, NA), predicted = c(463741.812236, 
14.7721571, 0.45, 0.6, 1.05, 1.45, 2.7, 3.125, 4.3, 5.6346081, 
7.05, 8.95, 10.35, 0.5, 0.7, 0.925, 1.2, 1.75, 65226323253857.9
)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x563cccc504c0>, index = integer(0))

test_dt[, predicted := round(exp(na.spline(log(b), x = a, na.rm = FALSE)), 7), by = group]


    group     a      b    predicted
 1:    K1 185.0     NA 4.637418e+05
 2:    K1 190.0     NA 1.477216e+01
 3:    K1 195.0  0.450 4.500000e-01
 4:    K1 200.0  0.600 6.000000e-01
 5:    K1 202.5  1.050 1.050000e+00
 6:    K1 205.0  1.450 1.450000e+00
 7:    K1 210.0  2.700 2.700000e+00
 8:    K1 212.5  3.125 3.125000e+00
 9:    K1 215.0  4.300 4.300000e+00
10:    K1 217.5     NA 5.634608e+00
11:    K1 220.0  7.050 7.050000e+00
12:    K1 222.5  8.950 8.950000e+00
13:    K1 225.0 10.350 1.035000e+01
14:    F1  22.0  0.500 5.000000e-01
15:    F1  23.0  0.700 7.000000e-01
16:    F1  24.0  0.925 9.250000e-01
17:    F1  25.0  1.200 1.200000e+00
18:    F1  26.0  1.750 1.750000e+00
19:    F1  35.0     NA 6.522632e+13
```

Comment: Why do say "nonlinear"? Why not interpolate linearly?

Comment: The reason I asked for nonlinear solution is because most of the linear interpolation functions predict the negative values.

Comment: If you have only positive values in your data then linear interpolation should not predict negative values. Do you have negative values in your data?

Comment: No, there are no negative values. However, the column ```b``` values are parabolic when plotted against column ```a```.

Comment: I see, for the C1 group the trend is decreasing at the end and you have 3 values to impute, so if you extend that line you would get to negative values... Is it acceptable to just impute linearly and then substitute all negative values with 0?

Comment: You are correct. However, making values zero is not desirable, though it can go deep into decimals like ```0.00001243```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, you have to decide the interpolation procedure based on scientific background. However, in order to avoid producing negative values, the log-transformation is useful. In the following, I combine that with a spline interpolation.

```
library(data.table)
test_dt = data.table(group = c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
                               "B1", "B1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1"), 
                     a = c(165, 170, 185, 195, 200, 210, 220, 240, 1, 1.5, 2, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 7, 10), 
                     b = c(1.925, 0.575, 0.3, NA, NA, 2.825, 9.05, 27.9, 3.775, 3.225, 2.75, 0.255, 
                           0.04, NA, NA, NA))

library(zoo)
test_dt[, c := exp(na.spline(log(b), x = a, na.rm = FALSE)), by = group]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test_dt, aes(x = a, color = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = c)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = c, color = "interpolated")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = b))
```

[image: resulting plot showing original and interpolated values]

Comment: Thanks, Roland, it worked well on the given dataset. While generalizing, I ran your solution on a different dataset and it seems like ```log``` is a double-edged sword. Can you please update your answer to interpolate the second dataset given in the question?

Comment: @Saurabh No, thank you. This site is for helping with programming issues. You don't have a programming issue. As I write in my answer, you need to find a sensible procedure for interpolation based on scientific background. I know nothing about the scientific background of your data. Also, extrapolation is a different beast than interpolation. Personally, I wouldn't want to extrapolate with an empirical approach.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinite ways to do this, each way having a certain set of assumptions. Here is one way, transforming the data into the log scale, performing linear interpolation, and then exponentiating the result. This should approach 0 but not be exactly 0.

```
library(zoo)
round(exp(na.spline(log(test_dt$b),na.rm=F,method="natural")),5)
 [1]  1.92500  0.57500  0.30000  0.39398  0.96937  2.82500  9.05000 27.90000  3.77500
[10]  3.22500  2.75000  0.25500  0.04000  0.00835  0.00175  0.00036
```

Also you should perform this separately for each group, so that there is no interpolation between groups.

Answer (score 2):

Try different methods of spline.
Also here I catch values lower than `0.0001` with `pmax`.

```
met <- c("fmm", "natural", "monoH.FC")
cbind(test_dt, lapply(setNames(met, met), function(met) {
  ave(seq_len(nrow(test_dt)), test_dt$group, FUN=function(i) {
    pmax(0.0001, splinefun(test_dt$a[i], test_dt$b[i], met)(test_dt$a[i]))
  }) }) )
#   group     a      b         fmm    natural   monoH.FC
#1     B1 165.0  1.925  1.92500000  1.9250000  1.9250000
#2     B1 170.0  0.575  0.57500000  0.5750000  0.5750000
#3     B1 185.0  0.300  0.30000000  0.3000000  0.3000000
#4     B1 195.0     NA  0.18981191  0.2372716  0.3751691
#5     B1 200.0     NA  0.40167712  0.4448177  0.6702794
#6     B1 210.0  2.825  2.82500000  2.8250000  2.8250000
#7     B1 220.0  9.050  9.05000000  9.0500000  9.0500000
#8     B1 240.0 27.900 27.90000000 27.9000000 27.9000000
#9     C1   1.0  3.775  3.77500000  3.7750000  3.7750000
#10    C1   1.5  3.225  3.22500000  3.2250000  3.2250000
#11    C1   2.0  2.750  2.75000000  2.7500000  2.7500000
#12    C1   4.5  0.255  0.25500000  0.2550000  0.2550000
#13    C1   5.0  0.040  0.04000000  0.0400000  0.0400000
#14    C1   5.5     NA  0.03038963  0.0001000  0.0001000
#15    C1   7.0     NA  1.67389631  0.0001000  0.0001000
#16    C1  10.0     NA 16.44642968  0.0001000  0.0001000
```